# Mysql select all entries from table 1 where there is no entries in table 2 with certain id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, table surveys and table survey_votes.

I want to select all surveys from table surveys

```
select * from surveys s
```

where there is no entry in table survey_votes equal to a certain user_id that references the survey from table surveys.

**Example:**

Table **surveys**

| id | question |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | What food do you like best? |
| 2 | What is your favorite car brand? |

Table **survey_votes**

| id | user_id | survey_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 101 | 1 |
| 1 | 101 | 2 |

- If user_id = 100, only survey 2 should be selected. If user_id = 101, no survey should be selected.
- If user_id = 102, both surveys should be selected.

The output table should consist of all columns of the original table surveys. Therefore, for user 102 it should look as follows:

| id | question |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | What food do you like best? |
| 2 | What is your favorite car brand? |

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: could you also give an example of how the output table should look like? Is it just a column with survey ids?

Comment: Sure, I updated my question. It should have the exact same collumns that the original surveys table has.

Comment: @Jasperjaks you need to use `JOIN` for that, but I'm sorry, I can't your exact need, so please follow this manual and you definitely will be able to solve your problem: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Comment: `select * from surveys s where s.id not in (select id from survey_votes)`

Comment: @Luuk thanks for your suggestion! However, the following query will select all surveys where no votes have been made yet:
select * from surveys s where s.id not in (select survey_id from suvey_votes)

What I want to achieve is that the query selects all surveys where a certain user has not yet voted but other users may have voted already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `survey` s WHERE s.id  NOT IN  
(SELECT sv.`survey_id` FROM `survey_votes` sv WHERE sv.`user_id`=102)
```

This should help, change "102" with your input user_id